# Perl substitution using a hash

Tags: regex, perl

```
open (FH,"report");
read(FH,$text,-s "report");

$fill{"place"} = "Dhahran";
$fill{"wdesc:desc"} = "hot";
$fill{"dayno.days"} = 4;

$text =~ s/%(\w+)%/$fill{$1}/g;

print $text;
```

This is the content of the "report" template file

```
"I am giving a course this week in %place%. The weather is %wdesc:desc%
and we're now onto day no %dayno.days%. It's great group of blokes on the
course but the room is like the weather - %wdesc:desc% and it gets hard to
follow late in the day."
```

For reasons that I won't go into, some of the keys in the hash I'll be using will have dots (.) or colons (:) in them, but the regex stops working for these, so for instance in the example above only `%place%` gets correctly replaced. By the way, my code is based on [this example](http://www.wellho.co.uk/resources/ex.php4?item=p212/filler).

Any help with the regex greatly appreciated, or maybe there's a better approach...

Comment: Of course it doesn't work with dots and colons. You're only capturing a string of *word* characters, which they are not.  `(\w+(?:[.:]\w+)*)` is a better expression, and if you're only ever expecting one dot or colon (at most): `(\w+(?:[.:]\w+)?)`. `(?:...)` means it's not a capture group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good answers so far, but you should also decide what you want to do with `%foo%` if `foo` isn't a key in the `%fill` hash.  Plausible options are:

- Replace it with an empty string (that's what the current solutions do, since `undef` is treated as an empty string in this context)
- Leave it alone, so `"%foo%"` stays as it is.
- Do some kind of error handling, perhaps printing a warning on `STDERR`, terminating the translation, or inserting an error indicator into the text.

Some other observations, not directly relevant to your question:

- You should use the three-argument version of `open`.
- That's not the cleanest way to read an entire file into a string.  For that matter, for what you're doing you might as well process the input one line at a time.

Here's how I might do it (this version leaves unrecognized `"%foo%"` strings alone):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %fill = ( place        => 'Dhahran',
             'wdesc:desc' => 'hot',
             'dayno.days' => 4 );

my $filename = 'report';

open my $FH,,'<', $filename or die "$filename: $!\n";
while (my $line = <$FH>) {
    foreach my $key (keys %fill) {
        $line =~ s/\Q%$key%/$fill{$key}/g;
    }
    print $line;
}
```

And here's a version that dies with an error message if there's an unrecognized key:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %fill = ( place        => 'Dhahran',
             'wdesc:desc' => 'hot',
             'dayno.days' => 4 );

my $filename = 'report';

open my $FH,,'<', $filename or die "$filename: $!\n";
while (my $line = <$FH>) {
    $line =~ s/%([^%]*)%/Replacement($1)/eg;
    print $line;
}

sub Replacement {
    my($key) = @_;
    if (exists $fill{$key}) {
        return $fill{$key};
    }
    else {
        die "Unrecognized key \"$key\" on line $.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `/%([^%]*)%/Replacement(\%fill, $1)/eg` would be even better.

Comment: `[^%\s]` would be best, as it'd avoid unnecessary borking when the text uses % without the special meaning.

Comment: @Chris: If you have to worry about that (which is a good idea) then moving to a better delimiter would be advised, something like `!!...!!` or `{{...}}`. And if you need to allow that stuff through then apply true laziness (rather than false laziness) and switch to Template Toolkit.

Comment: @Keith Ah yes of course unrecognised %foo% behaviour! Good point. I'm going with your initial example. cheers for the other tips also. Ta.

Comment: You could avoid looping and testing each variable against a separate regex with `my $regex = join("|", map quotemeta, keys %fill); s/%($regex)%/$fill{$1}/g;`

Comment: @Chris: Nice. I wonder if adding `$regex = qr/$regex/` would improve performance.

Comment: (If you're going to downvote, perhaps you could leave a comment explaining why?)

Answer (score 4):

You could loosen it right up and use "any sequence of anything that isn't a %" for the replaceable tokens:

```
$text =~ s/%([^%]+)%/$fill{$1}/g;
```

Comment: that'll work, but it might open it up to some further complications

Comment: Yeah, OP might want to add an `\s` in there too, `[^%\s]`.

Comment: Much better would be `[^\s%]`, anything not a % or whitespace.

Comment: @Qtax, @Chris: Better would be a full specification of what can be in the tokens. Based on the examples it is probably `[a-z.:]` but maybe more. Using `[\w\s.:]+` and then adding some whitespace stripping (to allow things like `%pan\ncakes%`) to Keith's `Replacement` approach would be the best.

Comment: Thanks all, really good suggestions. I'm going with one of Keith's since I need the unrecognised %foo% strings to remain untouched.

Answer (score 1):

http://codepad.org/G0WEDNyH

```
$text =~ s/%([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\:]+)%/$fill{$1}/g;
```

---

By default `\w` equates to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so you'll need to add in the `\.` and `\:`.

---

Comment: You can use `\w` (and related shortcuts) inside a character class and you don't need to escape the `.` inside a character class. Just `%([\w:.]+)%` would suffice and be less noisy.

Comment: I was going to do the same thing, but call me old-fashioned, I like being more explicit.  I think newer versions of Perl have `/a`, which `\w` does more than `a-zA-Z0-9_`, I just don't remember what the additionals are - they might be unicode equivalents